# MacBook Pro - How do I display in portrait for external monitor

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, macbook-pro

I got a fine and dandy mini DisplayPort to VGA adapter for my MacBook Pro - I hooked up an external Dell monitor and it works well in landscape.

Any tips on how to make the display on external monitor in portrait mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The option *should* be visible by default for an external monitor, but I assume since you're asking this question that it is not.

There's a little-known trick that works for the internal LCD on MacBooks; I suggest trying that:

1. Open System Preferences.
2. Hold down the <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd> keys, and click on the "Display" icon.
3. On the right side of the Display preferences, find the drop-down box labeled "Rotation".
4. Select the rotation you want.
5. Close System Preferences.
   [image: Rotation drop-down box in Display preferences]

Comment: This will rotate both screens. I want to rotate only the external display.

Comment: Hmm ... I was able to get this working with two external displays (with laptop in clamshell mode) and have one out of the two in portrait mode.

Comment: Yeah, it works for me on a per-display basis. There should be a different dialog box (and therefore a different "Rotation" drop-down control) for *each* monitor.